# Charging station flashing green. Not charging

Tags: roomba, stability

Charging station is flashing green. Roomba’s makes clicking sounds with error message. Have another charging station and the Roomba's charges there fine. I also move another Roomba ( have a total of 3) and they all do the same thing within this particular charger. I have cleaned the contacts frequently with smooth sanding paper and pencil eraser.

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: sandpaper and erasers are very bad for cleaning contacts ... they remove any protective coating which prevents corrosion

Comment: The best thing to clean electrical contacts like this is a [Magic Eraser](https://www.mrclean.com/en-us/shop-products/magic-erasers)